# Can I use PostgreSQL (pg) in the client-side (express/node.js)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, node.js, express

I want to use PostgreSQL  in the client side. is that possible? can i have this code?

in my server.js

```
   var pg = require('pg');
```

in my client side

```
     var conString = "postgres://postgres:pass@localhost/mydb";
     var client = new pg.Client(conString);
     client.connect();
     var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM users ");        
     query.on('row', function(row) {
             alert(row.name);
     });
```

i tried this code but nothing happened. though can i have a code similar to this, where i  connect PostgreSQL and use queries on the client scripts.

Comment: This would be a huge security risk. You should get data on the backend and pass it to the client.

Comment: Did you get any errors on the client or server side?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that's (obviously) not possible. You wouldn't want to let a client access your database directly anyway. Besides that, even though you use JS on both the client and server side it's not different from what happens if you use e.g. PHP or Python on the server - the only communication between it is possible via AJAX and regular http requests.

Comment: thanks for the info. I just realized it would be so easy to hack the site if you would allow the client to use the database.

Comment: CouchApps have clients access the database directly, it's not insecure if you have decent validation baked into your database.

Comment: Perhaps someone should enlighten me as to why this is so obvious? And why you'd never allow a client to connect to your database, assuming your database requires authentication? Seems like a reasonable supposition to me.

Comment: Authentication is one aspect of the access. We need to have appropriate authorization in place as well. Implementing authorization with base DBMS features is not easy and often may not even provide necessary capability to match business requirements.

Comment: @Amitabh it's basically not true. I may want to allow direct readonly access to my database. Without this feature I have to implement a thin proxy that should be developed, tested, shipped and maintained just because database doesn't support direct HTTP calls.