# How to Connect to postgres db from angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, heroku

I want to store some user values, name and email, in a Postgres DB on an app hosted by Heroku. This is the code in my controller;

```
var pg = require('pg');
...
$scope.addUser = function() {
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
        var query = client.query('INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (\'' + $scope.user.name + '\', \'' + $scope.user.email + '\')');

        query.on('row', function(row) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
        });
    });
};
```

I get an error saying that require is not defined, which I know is because it is not supported client side. I tried using browserify on the controller file, then updating the `<script>` tag in the index.html that sources the file. This leads to another error.

Removing the `var pg = require('pg');` gives a "ReferenceError: pg is not defined". I just want to connect to the Postgres DB from my app and insert some values. Am I on the right track or should I be going about this differently?

Comment: The pg library is for node not an angular client app.

Comment: Is there another way to use postgres from angular?

Comment: You build a server side component that angular can access.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying, and that's what I'm about to do. Thanks

Comment: re: PostgreSQL and Angular: check out the PEAN project, based on the MEAN.JS boilerplate. PostgreSQL/Sequelize, Express, Angular, Node: https://github.com/StetSolutions/pean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Can I use PostgreSQL (pg) in the client-side (express/node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444943/can-i-use-postgresql-pg-in-the-client-side-express-node-js) as to why you can't let clients connect directly to your database. You either want to write a (lightweight) server app (probably using Node.js), or you should consider a backend-as-a-service (BaaS) like [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) or [IrisCouch](https://www.iriscouch.com/) so that you don't need to develop the backend at all.